# React Native Facebook Login wouldn't redirect back to app in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, react-native

I'm having an issue with react native facebook login. Android version works perfectly, but iOS version won't redirect back to app once authenticated via Facebook app. Probably this is not something wrong with the code but something wrong with App settings in facebook's dev portal. How to redirect back to iOS app once authenticated via Facebook native app ?

My code,

```
  facebookLogin() {
    const { fbLoginRequest } = this.props;
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email', 'user_birthday'])
      .then(result => {
        if (!result.isCancelled) {
          AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(data => {
            fbLoginRequest({ token: data.accessToken.toString() });
            console.log(data.accessToken.toString());
          });
        }
      }, error => {
        console.log('An error occurred: ', error);
        toast.negative(error);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        toast.negative(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: The fact that it works on Android is suspicious of a misconfiguration over on the iOS side. I would start by making sure your FB app id is correct in `Info.plist`, and checking to see if you're getting anything useful back from FB. If the login is all going swimmingly, make sure you've completed all the configuration steps listed in the `react-native-facebook-login` docs, perhaps particularly [AppDelegate.m modifications](https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login#appdelegatem-modifications).

Comment: Did you get this to work? Running into the same issue.

Comment: @wvicioso yes, as Rich mentioned we had missed some AppDelegate methods in the native iOS project.

Answer (score 0):

You should be check `AppDelegate.m` file in iOS code,

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
           openURL:(NSURL *)url
           sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
           annotation:(id)annotation {

           BOOL handledFB = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                openURL:url
                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                annotation:annotation
                   ];

           BOOL handledRCT = [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];

           return handledFB || handledRCT;
   }
```

It's work for me.